# Why Wednesday tells Shadow to "be nice, but not too nice" to Easter?

Tags: american-gods

When Wednesday and Shadow are about to visit Easter, Wednesday says:

> Be nice to the lady we are visiting. But not too nice. [...]
>   
>   “Let me put it bluntly,” said Wednesday. “You must be very cautious around the lady we are
>   visiting. She might take a fancy to you, and that would be bad.” 
>   “Is she your girlfriend or something?” 
>   “Not for all the little plastic toys in China,” said Wednesday, agreeably

I can see few reasons for this warning, but I can't find enough arguments for any of them:

1. **Wednesday might be jealous** : maybe there was something between those two and he simply doesn't want his employee to get flirty with his old squeeze.
2. **Easter might be dangerous** - gods ARE dangerous - just look at Bilquis, who regularly devours her lovers
3. **Easter might threaten Wednesday's plans** - he needs Shadow for his Grand Scheme and if the quite powerful goddess would try to steal him... well, things could get complicated.

I have problems believing in case 1 - Wednesday had many lovers, I doubt that he would care for one... But then one of his charms is " no woman  I want will ever want another", so I might be wrong...

I don't want to believe in case 2 - Easter is sweet and lovely, she doesn't expect human sacrifice.

The 3rd case seems most likely, but then why risking bringing Shadow to her in the first place?

Comment: Mix of 2 and 3? The grand plan requires an attempt to recruit anyone, since power on the sidelines doesn't benefit Wednesday.  Shadow needs to be around.  Easter wouldn't necessarily eat Shadow, but as a goddess of rebirth and spring's fertility, she could present any number of other derailments or temptations that could pull Shadow away from Wednesday.